# Positioning Multiple Images in A Grid Using CSS without changing the HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position multiple images in a grid with small caption underneath each of them, like so:

[image: Desired outcome]

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="letters">
    <h3>British Sign Language: Letters</h3>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/A.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;A&quot;" title="&quot;A&quot;">
    <p>A - Alfa</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/B.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;B&quot;" title="&quot;B&quot;">
    <p>B - Bravo</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/C.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;C&quot;" title="&quot;C&quot;">
    <p>C - Charlie</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/D.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;D&quot;" title="&quot;D&quot;">
    <p>D - Delta</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/E.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;E&quot;" title="&quot;E&quot;">
    <p>E - Echo</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/F.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;F&quot;" title="&quot;F&quot;">
    <p>F - Foxtrot</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/G.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;G&quot;" title="&quot;G&quot;">
    <p>G - Golf</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/H.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;H&quot;" title="&quot;H&quot;">
    <p>H - Hotel</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/I.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;I&quot;" title="&quot;I&quot;">
    <p>I - India</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/J.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;J&quot;" title="&quot;J&quot;">
    <p>J - Juliet</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/K.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;K&quot;" title="&quot;K&quot;">
    <p>K - Kilo</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/L.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;L&quot;" title="&quot;L&quot;">
    <p>L - Lima</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/M.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;M&quot;" title="&quot;M&quot;">
    <p>M - Mike</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/N.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;N&quot;" title="&quot;N&quot;">
    <p>N - November</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/O.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;O&quot;" title="&quot;O&quot;">
    <p>O - Oscar</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/P.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;P&quot;" title="&quot;P&quot;">
    <p>P - Papa</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/Q.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;Q&quot;" title="&quot;Q&quot;">
    <p>Q - Quebec</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/R.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;R&quot;" title="&quot;R&quot;">
    <p>R - Romeo</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/S.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;S&quot;" title="&quot;S&quot;">
    <p>S - Sierra</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/T.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;T&quot;" title="&quot;T&quot;">
    <p>T - Tango</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/U.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;U&quot;" title="&quot;U&quot;">
    <p>U - Uniform</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/V.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;V&quot;" title="&quot;V&quot;">
    <p>V - Victor</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/W.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;W&quot;" title="&quot;W&quot;">
    <p>W - Whiskey</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/X.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;X&quot;" title="&quot;X&quot;">
    <p>X - Xray</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/Y.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;Y&quot;" title="&quot;Y&quot;">
    <p>Y - Yankee</p>
    <img src="./Sign Language_files/Z.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;Z&quot;" title="&quot;Z&quot;">
    <p>Z - Zulu</p>
      </div>
```

I've tried playing around with both float and display but this all I can manage:

[image: What I've done]

I've done it by setting the images and paragraph to display inline as shown below:

```
#letters img, #letters p{
    display: inline;
}
```

So my question is: Is it possible to align both the images and the paragraphs in a grid WITHOUT changing the HTML? If it's possible then what should I look into?
I went through both float and display at w3schools but nothing seems to be working for me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you can't change HTML markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot change the HTML, here is an idea using flexbox:

```css
#letters {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 520px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  align-content: flex-start;
  position:relative;
}

h3 {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="letters">
  <h3>British Sign Language: Letters</h3>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/A.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;A&quot;" title="&quot;A&quot;">
  <p>A - Alfa</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/B.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;B&quot;" title="&quot;B&quot;">
  <p>B - Bravo</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/C.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;C&quot;" title="&quot;C&quot;">
  <p>C - Charlie</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/D.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;D&quot;" title="&quot;D&quot;">
  <p>D - Delta</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/E.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;E&quot;" title="&quot;E&quot;">
  <p>E - Echo</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/F.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;F&quot;" title="&quot;F&quot;">
  <p>F - Foxtrot</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/G.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;G&quot;" title="&quot;G&quot;">
  <p>G - Golf</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/H.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;H&quot;" title="&quot;H&quot;">
  <p>H - Hotel</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/I.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;I&quot;" title="&quot;I&quot;">
  <p>I - India</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/J.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;J&quot;" title="&quot;J&quot;">
  <p>J - Juliet</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/K.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;K&quot;" title="&quot;K&quot;">
  <p>K - Kilo</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/L.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;L&quot;" title="&quot;L&quot;">
  <p>L - Lima</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/M.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;M&quot;" title="&quot;M&quot;">
  <p>M - Mike</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/N.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;N&quot;" title="&quot;N&quot;">
  <p>N - November</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/O.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;O&quot;" title="&quot;O&quot;">
  <p>O - Oscar</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/P.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;P&quot;" title="&quot;P&quot;">
  <p>P - Papa</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/Q.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;Q&quot;" title="&quot;Q&quot;">
  <p>Q - Quebec</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/R.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;R&quot;" title="&quot;R&quot;">
  <p>R - Romeo</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/S.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;S&quot;" title="&quot;S&quot;">
  <p>S - Sierra</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/T.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;T&quot;" title="&quot;T&quot;">
  <p>T - Tango</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/U.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;U&quot;" title="&quot;U&quot;">
  <p>U - Uniform</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/V.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;V&quot;" title="&quot;V&quot;">
  <p>V - Victor</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/W.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;W&quot;" title="&quot;W&quot;">
  <p>W - Whiskey</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/X.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;X&quot;" title="&quot;X&quot;">
  <p>X - Xray</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/Y.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;Y&quot;" title="&quot;Y&quot;">
  <p>Y - Yankee</p>
  <img src="./Sign Language_files/Z.png" height="100" width="100" alt="&quot;Z&quot;" title="&quot;Z&quot;">
  <p>Z - Zulu</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! but is it possible for the images to go that way >> so its A>B>C

Comment: @ArnoldR if you cannot change the html you are limitied :) you can play with the `order` property if you want